# Is "come again" an absolute slang?

Tags: slang, business-language, expression-choice

I am not a native English speaker and use the expression "*come again*" in various forms such as "*Come again, please*" or "*Can you come again?*". I consider it to be a general expression which can also be used in formal speak. Is it not the case?

In my search for the answer I read through [this](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/5040/about-the-usage-of-term-come-again) question that discusses the sexual connotation of the phrase. But I could not definitively figure out *if the expression can be used in a formal sense*.

How does it fare compared to using "*Pardon*" or "*Sorry*" in the same context?

Comment: *come again?* Informal what did you say? http://www.thefreedictionary.com/come+again http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=come%20again

Comment: I certainly wouldn't use this in a formal written document. I think in speech, it could be used in a reasonably formal setting.

Comment: @PeterShor: Yes, I do understand that it would be awkward in a formal document but I am only concerned with its spoken formal usage.

Comment: Don't use it formally. Instead use _Please repeat that_

Comment: You’ll have to define what “an absolute slang” is. In the first place, there is no such thing as “a” slang, since *slang* is not a count noun.  In the second place, neither does it make any sense to apply “absolute” here.  What do you really mean?

Comment: @tchrist: I have a feeling that am not explaining things correctly, so I'll try again. By "_absolute_" I meant, if the phrase "come again" is slang in all sense of the language or it is possible to be use it in formal speak as well? Hope this explanation helps.

Answer (score 1):

"*Come again?*" as a question has a very different meaning from "*Can you come again?*". The former is an informal way of asking the speaker to repeat themselves (as if you didn't understand or hear them) - the latter however is politely requesting that a person comes to a specific location on another occasion.

So in that vein the former is very much slang, and wouldn't generally be used in a formal context. As a general rule, formal speech or text should avoid phrases or colloquialisms that could be misinterpreted or have alternate meanings.

Comment: That makes sense, the phrase in question after-all has a sexual connotation to it and could be misinterpreted. But wouldn't "_Can you come again?_" be self explanatory to not mean asking the other party to a location at another time, according to the context?

Comment: I can't think of a context where the meaning of "_Can you come again?_" changes. The added formality forces a given meaning.

Comment: to support @PhonicUK, I want to say that I thought your examples and question were speaking about inviting a person back to a specific location. It was only until the very last sentence about "Pardon" that I even realized that the question was about repeating a statement.